# Which template do Rails use when creating new app when using (without -m option)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create rails app, I sometime like to delete some line of code or remove some gems that I have no use for. Or always added several gems that I used often along with some line of codes (that is where template comes in with -m option when using `rails new <appname> -m <path_to_template>`

But what template does rails use when using `rails new <appname>` (without -m options)?

I researched this on the Net and don't seems to find that specific answer.

thanks,

John

Comment: I think the easiest way how to get your answer is install the app with by default and check the files by yourself, because i also couldn't find the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rails new <appname> -m <path_to_template>` does not change the template, it runs the template after the normal `rails new` process. You always get what `rails new` gives you. The template option just allows you to do more things afterwards.

At the top of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html ...

> Application templates are simple Ruby files containing DSL for adding gems/initializers etc. to your freshly created Rails project or an existing Rails project.

Comment: @john-towery if this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer. If not, let me know what you are missing.

Comment: Sorry. You did partially answered my question that I always get what `rails new` do.
I just wonder how to change the default setting. I want to create new rails app with my 'default' setting instead of having to go thru some things to delete all the unnecessary defaults (like some of those gems I don't need in `Gemfile`).
My other option is to just create a template, and within that template there are two part..first part is to delete unnecessary codes and second part I add in specific setting/codes/etc.

Comment: It depends what you need to remove. If you run `rails new --help` you will see the list of options for features you can remove by default. For example, if you run `rails new --skip-active-record blog` you will skip the creation of active record. There are a bunch of other "skip" flags that you will find when you run `rails new --help`

Comment: Can the options be used within template? like `--skip-active-record`? It would be easier that way. Let me read more documentation on this.

Comment: There might be a way but it is not the normal way. As I stated earlier, the template only executes after the default rails new finishes. You could add code to remove active record (or any other of the skips) in the template but that seems error-prone. Usually what I do in my templates is add a comment to the top that says how to run it. `# run this command with rails new --skip-active-record` Another thing to look at is https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer That project sounds like something you could use or base your templates off of